# How to shade portions of a matplotlib axis face based on timeseries values

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given data with timeseries and values associated with the timeseries, I'd like to shade the background of the axis plot depending on the value of the timeseries in order to highlight values which have particular meanings relating to the times (eg - could be a season, or opening hours etc).

I don't really know how to do this - but do have a picture of the sort of thing I mean:
[image]

I don't work with timeseries much, but I've tried to create a dataset which should be suitable for example data:

```py
import io

so_data = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        "x,y,plt_mask\n2023-03-22 02:29:51,0.0,False\n2023-03-22 03:20:26,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 00:51:06,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 01:29:42,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 04:48:22,23.081085,False\n2023-03-23 07:13:11,50.0,True\n2023-03-23 08:46:27,50.0,True\n2023-03-23 12:34:13,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 12:46:35,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 16:02:13,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 17:58:47,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 18:34:27,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 20:28:29,1.0,False\n2023-03-24 05:25:20,0.0,True\n2023-03-24 09:03:36,0.0,True\n2023-03-24 09:06:09,0.0,True\n2023-03-24 10:53:44,70.0,True\n2023-03-24 13:10:03,1273.676636,False\n2023-03-24 17:03:16,21.0,False\n2023-03-24 18:22:23,1.0,False\n"
    )
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
so_data

fig.autofmt_xdate()

xfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

ax.plot(so_data["x"], so_data["y"])
```

Here the axis background should be a different colour (green / whatever) when the `plt_mask` value is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way to do that using the example you provided, pandas, and `ax.fill_betweenx` (doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import io
import pandas as pd

so_data = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        "x,y,plt_mask\n2023-03-22 02:29:51,0.0,False\n2023-03-22 03:20:26,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 00:51:06,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 01:29:42,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 04:48:22,23.081085,False\n2023-03-23 07:13:11,50.0,True\n2023-03-23 08:46:27,50.0,True\n2023-03-23 12:34:13,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 12:46:35,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 16:02:13,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 17:58:47,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 18:34:27,0.0,False\n2023-03-23 20:28:29,1.0,False\n2023-03-24 05:25:20,0.0,True\n2023-03-24 09:03:36,0.0,True\n2023-03-24 09:06:09,0.0,True\n2023-03-24 10:53:44,70.0,True\n2023-03-24 13:10:03,1273.676636,False\n2023-03-24 17:03:16,21.0,False\n2023-03-24 18:22:23,1.0,False\n"
    )
)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.autofmt_xdate()

df_mask_true=so_data.loc[so_data['plt_mask']==True] #create a dataframe from the rows with plt_mask==True

ax.plot(so_data["x"], so_data["y"])

[ax.fill_betweenx([so_data['y'].min(),so_data['y'].max()],x,so_data['x'].iloc[so_data.index[so_data['x']==x]+1],facecolor='k',alpha=0.4)  for x in df_mask_true['x']] #fill the background between x and x+1 with grey
```

[image]